# How do I add CSS to part of another object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms

I have a set of tables across pages that are always called tblData. I would like to be able to set the CSS properties for the elemenets inside the table e.g. the labels, the column styles, the text etc.

At the moment I am doing it like this

```
#tblData{
style...}

.dataColumn{
style...}
```

But I would like to consolidate them somehow into the tblData class so I only need to add this one class to complete the layout.

This is what I already have to try and set the styles of the textboxes and labels but the label and textbox elements don't work:

```
.tblData {
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 200px;
    color: rgb(45,40,128);
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin-top:3px;

}
/*Class for the labels*/
.tblData label {
    width: 13%;
    color:black;
    border-radius:3px;
    font-family:verdana;
    border-radius:3px;
    border-color:rgba(45,40,128,0.75);
    border-width:1px;

}
/*Class for the data textboxes*/
.tblData textbox {
    border-color: rgba(45,40,128,0.75);
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color:rgba(45,40,128,0.10);
    font-family:Verdana;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

This is a table example (note not complete because it's too large)

```
  <table id="ContactsTable" class="tblData">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:Label ID="lblContact" runat="server" Text="Contact" CssClass="Datalabelcolumn"></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="Datatextbox" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wish to have a class applied to the table itself, you can add specific CSS selectors to isolate certain elements of the table itself, such as its rows or columns e.g.:

```
#tblData td{

/* sets cell styling */

}

#tblData tr{

/* sets row styling */

}

#tblData th{

/* sets head styling */

}

#tblData tr td:first-child{

/* sets styling of first column  */

}

#tblData tr td:last-child{

/* sets styling of last column  */

}

#tblData tr td:nth-child(n){

/* sets styling of specific column (change n to number)  */

}
```

The above basically says take the element with the id `tblData` then select the child elements which fit the following selectors. It may also be worth having a look at the [W3 selector documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) for further info.

Here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Py6cr/)** with some example selectors.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same for textboxes or labels within the table?

Comment: @connersz Absolutely, you can simply use e.g. `#tblData label{}` or `#tblData input[type=text]{}`

Comment: I have tried doing this but it doesnt work. Are you sure it will work with asp.net controls?

Comment: @connersz, can you add to your question your HTML and explain what you've already tried?

Comment: would you mind upvoting my answer since I added my code.